# Как сделать замену каждого n-го символа в строке?

Tags: javascript

Делаю валидацию формы оплаты, мне нужно чтобы после каждого 4 символа был пробел.

HTML

```
<input class="card-input" required name="card-number" id="cardNumber">
```

JS

```
function validation(input, maxlength) {
    input.oninput = () => {
            input.value = input.value.replace(/[^\d]/g, '').substr(0, maxlength)  
    }
}
validation(cardNumber, 19)
```

[image: скрин консоли]

Как так выходит, что он вообще не меняет символ, задаваемый по индексу?

Comment: Что конкретно хотите сделать? Банальная проверка на соответствие - `/^[0-9]{4}\s[0-9]{4}\s[0-9]{4}\s[0-9]{4}$/.test("4342 2434 4323 2345")`

Comment: Зачем вам для валидации пробелы?

Comment: @Эникейщик это же часть карты) куда без них

Comment: Нет, это не часть карты вообще никак.

Comment: @Эникейщик сарказм) есть подозрение что ТС хочет что-то такое `document.querySelector('input').addEventListener("input", e => e.target.value = e.target.value.replace(/\s/g, '').split(/(\d{4})/g).join(' ').trim());` - добавление пробела при вводе, эдакий красивый ввод